# dangerouslySetInnerHTML getting data from S3 bucket object in Serverless React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

My goal is to read an HTML document from an S3 Bucket, and display it in the browser using Serverless React. The document contains HTML that should be rendered in the browser.  Previous research seems to show that I need to use "dangerouslySetInnerHTML", so I'm trying that.

React code in App.tsx:

```
import "./App.css";

import * as React from "react";

import useConfig from "./components/useConfig";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import logoPsych from "./psych_mind_logo.jpg"


/**
 * Our Web Application
 */
export default function App() {
  const config = useConfig();

  function createPageBodyTest() {
    let myHtml = 'First &middot; Second'; 
    return {__html: myHtml};
  }

  async function createPageBody() {
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

    const params = {
      Bucket: 'mybucket',
      Key: 'MyFile1.html'
    }
    let s3 = new AWS.S3();
    /*
    let pageBody = async function() {
      // get s3 file and create stream
      const contentsOfS3Item = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();
      return contentsOfS3Item;
      }  
      */
      const response = await s3.getObject(params).promise() // await the promise
      const fileContent = response.Body.toString('utf-8');      
    return {__html: fileContent};
  }

  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
         <img src={logoPsych} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
         <h1 className="App-title">CognitivePsychology.com</h1>
      </header>
      <p className="App-intro">
         <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createPageBody()} />; 
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If I put createPageBodyTest instead of createPageBody I don't get any error in VSCode, but as the code is above, I see this (with the mouse-over error displayed).  I'm guessing it is because if have an async function.

[image]

If I ignore that, and deploy it anyway, the server side refers to this url: https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=61

Comment: I believe it is because you are returning a promise. Have you tried creating a state, giving it a default value and then setting the state once the promise has been resolved and then using the state as the parameter for dangerouslySetInnerHtml? I don't have any AWS stuff set up so i cannot test it myself.

Comment: Thanks, that points me in the right direction I think.  Do I need to be in a class to use State?  Seems like I'm just in a function called App(), and I would have to add a class constructor https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: Or can I call AWS without a promise?

Comment: I am not sure about AWS stuff but I doubt you can get around handling a promise. You can use states in a class but since you are using a functional component you should use the useState hook either imported from react or just typed as React.useState. I'm gonna make an answer with an example of what I think is gonna work

Comment: I was thinking I can create a class called getBlog, let it do the AWS call, call it from function App(), and set the state and return the DIV tag.  It's been a couple of years since I played with React.

Comment: If you make a new class to handle the AWS stuff, you might as well make the state in that class and then return the div with dangerouslysethtml and put the class in its stead. But what is best I don't know I just started learning react a couple months ago myself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this because you are returning a promise. I think it can be solved by inputting a placeholder and then exchanging that with what you actually want there once the promise has been resolved. You could do this with states:

```
export default function App() {
const [html, setHtml] = React.useState({ __html: '<div>Placeholder text</div>'})

async function createPageBody() {
    // AWS stuff
    // Resolve the promise
    setHtml({ __html: resolvedPromise })
}

return (
    <div className='App'>
        <header className='App-header'>
            <img src={logoPsych} className='App-logo' alt='logo' />
            <h1 className='App-title'>CognitivePsychology.com</h1>
        </header>
        <p className='App-intro'>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={html} />;
        </p>
    </div>
);
```

If you are using TypeScript replace the useState for:

```
const [html, setHtml] = React.useState<{ __html: string}>({ __html: '<div>Placeholder text</div>'})
```

You could also do the same with a separate component for handling AWS stuff:

**App.?sx**

```
export default function App() {
return (
    <div className='App'>
        <header className='App-header'>
            <img src={logoPsych} className='App-logo' alt='logo' />
            <h1 className='App-title'>CognitivePsychology.com</h1>
        </header>
        <p className='App-intro'>
            <getBlog />;
        </p>
    </div>
);
```

**getBlog.?sx**

```
export default function getBlog() {
    const [html, setHtml] = React.useState({ __html: '<div>Placeholder text</div>'})

    async function createPageBody() {
        // AWS stuff
        // Resolve the promise
        setHtml({ __html: resolvedPromise })
    }

    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={html} />;
}
```

I have no experience using AWS but I believe you should be able to handle your promise doing something like:

```
async function createPageBody() {
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

    const params = {
      Bucket: 'mybucket',
      Key: 'MyFile1.html'
    }
    let s3 = new AWS.S3();
    const response = await s3.getObject(params).promise() // await the promise
    response.then((data) => {
        setHtml({ __html: data.data.you.want.to.react })
    }, (error) => {
        // Handle error
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying this.  But how/where should createPageBody get called?  I'm getting the default value.  I'm also trying to add some console.log's to try to figure out what is happening.  I think you are right about me missing the .then on my promise.

Comment: You should probably call createPageBody in a useEffect. The syntaxt for this would just be React.useEffect(() => { createPageBody() }, []). And just place it in the component where you want to call the function

Comment: Before I saw your response, I just added a call, and I see from my console.log I got into the call.  I think my problem now is the s3.getObject/promise/then/error logic which I'm working on. Thanks

Comment: Still struggling - See new question based on your technique.  The problem is definitely with S3 and the awaits...