# Serverless React - getting HTML from S3 Bucket - how to call async from sync

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3, async-await, serverless-framework

Based on this question I posted earlier today, I have added some logging and narrow in that the problem is with the s3.GetObject.

NOTE: I've seen about 6 different ways to do the S3 get object, and have tried a few of them.  My mind is mush now... The current one I'm using is based on this: https://blog.tomasztarnowski.com/how-to-fetch-and-update-s3-files-with-aws-lambda-serverless-framework-and-typescript
But I added the try/catch around it.

I think now this better describes my problem:
[s3.getObject().promise() never returns anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55228171/s3-getobject-promise-never-returns-anything)
I'm exploring all the options there.
But since I'm running with Serverless and React - any ideas specific to that would be greatly appreciated.

This is my current code.  I basically took the demo from Serverless/React (running on AWS Lambda) and am I'm just trying to load some HTML from S3 and show in the browser web page.
I'm trying to use React state to set the value on the web page to the value from S3 (based on [dangerouslySetInnerHTML getting data from S3 bucket object in Serverless React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75188028/dangerouslysetinnerhtml-getting-data-from-s3-bucket-object-in-serverless-react)).

I have defined this in my serverless.yml file:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-plugin-scripts
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-s3-deploy
  - serverless-iam-roles-per-function
functions:
  serve:
    handler: handler.serve
    events:
      - http:
          path: /
          method: any
          cors: true
      - http:
          path: /{any+}
          method: any
          cors: true
    iamRoleStatementsName: LambdaGetS3BucketCognitivePsychologyCmsDemo
    iamRoleStatements: 
      - Effect: Allow 
        Action: 
           - s3:GetObject 
        Resource: arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*
```

Based on what I see in the log (see in yellow in picture below), I think await promise is the problem.  It doesn't seem to be waiting.
If I'm getting security error, I want to log that.

How do you call an async routine from a sync routine?
I tried an approach from this page, to wrap my call in a nameless async function.

```
import "./App.css";

import * as React from "react";

import useConfig from "./components/useConfig";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import logoPsych from "./psych_mind_logo.jpg"


/**
 * Our Web Application
 */
export default function App() {

  console.log("Start: 'function App()'" );

  const [html, setHtml] = 
       React.useState<{ __html: string}>({ __html: '<h1>Blog goes here</h1>'})

  const config = useConfig();

  async function createPageBody() {

      console.log("function createPageBody");
      const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

      const params = {
        Bucket: 'mybucket',
        Key: 'myObjectFileName.html'
      }
      // console.log(params);
      let s3 = new AWS.S3();


      // getting the object with aws-sdk, ".promise()" is required to use async-await
      console.log("before await s3.getObject.promise");

      try {
          const output = await s3
            .getObject(params)
            .promise();
          console.log("after await s3.getObject.promise");
          const fileContents = output.Body?.toString() || "<h1>Failed to get S3 File/Body</h1>";
          console.log("S3 fileContents=");
          console.log(fileContents);
          setHtml({ __html: fileContents})      
      } catch (e) {
          console.log("s3.getObject: error=" + e.message); 
          setHtml({ __html: e.message})      
      }


      // output.Body contains the content of the S3 JSON file
      // we expect the file to not be empty, script doesn't fail if it is empty though


    return;  
           
  }         



  console.log("About to call createPageBody");
  (async() => {
      await createPageBody(); 
  })
  console.log("Back from call createPageBody");
  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
         <img src={logoPsych} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
         <h1 className="App-title">CognitivePsychology.com</h1>
      </header>
      <p className="App-intro">
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={html} />
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is what the CloudWatch log shows from the execution of the Lambda service.  None of the falling logs show up there:

```
console.log("before await s3.getObject.promise");
console.log("after await s3.getObject.promise");
console.log("s3.getObject: error=" + e.message);
```

[image]

Some of my previous tests (before I put the nameless async around the call to createPageBody) have been showing "h1>Blog goes here" in the browser, the default value for the state.  But the above code shows nothing in the browser.

Comment: I checked the Lambda - No VPC configuration - This function isn't connected to a VPC.

Comment: Well you can't do it like this you've basically created a nameless function that you cannot call and then call createPageBody() inside which means it never gets called no matter what. If you just replace the nameless function with the following: React.useEffect(() => createPageBody(), []). I believe you do not need the async await since nothing is waiting later on in the statement

Comment: @LazyJ - tried that - no errors, but the console.log statements in my createPageBody function didn't show in the Cloudwatch log.

Comment: in React.useState you will not able to get the required function to import the module so you have to add this in a separate file and import it as a function in it.